# Possible memory leak with StringBuilder?

Tags: java, file-io, memory-leaks

I am using a `StringBuilder` to create a `File` object, but am also using it to see if the directory the file is located inside of exists:

```
StringBuilder sbFile = new StringBuilder();
sbFile.append("/home/logs/");

File oFile = new File(sbFile.toString());

if(!oFile.exists())
    oFile.mkdir();

sbFile.append("MyLogFile.log");

oFile = new File(sbFile.toString());
```

But I am worried that reusing the same `oFile` reference on two different "versions" of the string builder (`/home/logs/` vs `/home/logs/MyLogFile.log`) will create a memory leak.  If so, how should I write this differently?

Comment: Is the string returned by `toString()` not a copy of the string stored in the `StringBuilder`, thus not causing any sort of dangling references? -- Ah, it seems that is indeed the case, according to Jonathan W.

Comment: it's my understanding it will not, once you create a 'new file' on top of the old one the old one is released and available for pickup by the GC.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no memory leak. The instance of `File` created for the first time, will be garbage-collected by JVM when it is no longer used.

The other thing is that you don't really need to use `StringBuilder`. `File` class has a constructor that takes a *parent* and a filename. Your example could look like this:

```
File parent = new File("/home/logs/");
if(!parent.exists())
    parent.mkdir();

File file = new File(parent, "MyLogFile.log");
// TODO: do something with file...
```

Also, you may be interested in [how garbage collection works in Java](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/04/garbage-collection-in-java.html).

Answer (score 3):

You don't have anything to worry about. Strings are immutable in Java and won't give you memory leaks (at least not the way you're using them). `sbFile.toString()` creates a new immutable String each time you call it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no memory leak, the garbage collector returns for reuse memory of your old unused objects.

With regards to `File oFile` you use 2 different objects in your code. First object you create here:

```
File oFile = new File(sbFile.toString());
```

When you use oFile reference again and the old object is not referenced anywhere it is waiting for garbage collecting.

With regards to `StringBuilder sbFile` anytime you use its toString() method a new immutable String object is created (String objects in Java are always immutable).  So in the second `sbFile.toString()` invocation second String object is created and the first String object could be safely removed by garbage collector.